# git publish part of repo to remote repo

Tags: git

I have a repo that consist of 4 directories. Each directory contain different part of the project

The 4 directory is : **asset, backend, mobileapp, util**

**backend** contain a nodejs project that act as a backend, the **mobileapp** will contain android and ios project

I want to push just the **backend** folder to a live repo (I want to push it to a App Service at Azure) without the other 3 directories...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can push to a repo is a branch. If you want to push only one directory you need to create a branch or a separate repo with just that subdirectory.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/359759/7976758 on how to detach a subdirectory into a separate Git repository.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you can find detailed instruction](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/) how to do it.
I recommend to create separate local clone of repo first since you will rewrite history.

The most important part is this command:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter FOLDER-NAME  BRANCH-NAME
```